# Edit URL in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to show my link in url like that:

http://localhost:60000/Admin/myControlerName/myActionName/3/7/2

**This is my routConfig:**

[image]

**This is my contoller:**

[image]

**This is my action link:**

[image]

Mylink shows in url like that:

http://localhost:60000/Admin/myControlerName/myActionName/?id1=3&id2=7&id3=2

But i want to show like that:

http://localhost:60000/Admin/myControlerName/myActionName/3/7/2

Where is my wrong? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 different issues here. First of all, it won't work right to make 3 optional parameters on a route. Only the last (right most) parameter can be optional. So, you need two routes to enable all of the combinations of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 segments in the URL.

```
// This will match URLs 4 or 5 segments in length such as:
//
//   /Home/Index/2/3
//   /Home/Index/2/3/4
//
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "4-5Segments",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id2}/{id3}",
    defaults: new { id3 = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

// This will match URLs 0, 1, 2, or 3 segments in length such as:
//
//   /
//   /Home
//   /Home/Index/
//   /Home/Index/2
//
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Secondly, your ActionLink is not matching because you have specified the route value as `id1`, but in your route the value is `id`. So, you need to change `ActionLink` as follows.

```
@Html.ActionLink("my text", "myActionName", "myControllerName", new { id = 3, id2 = 7, id3 = 2}, null)
```

This assumes you have correctly set up your controller:

```
public class myControllerNameController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /myActionName/

    public ActionResult myActionName(int id = 0, int id2 = 0, int id3 = 0)
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

See the [working demo here](https://github.com/NightOwl888/MVC5_SO_32669600).

> For future reference, please provide the code as text. It is really hard to copy and edit an image, so you are much less likely to get an answer.

Comment: For it to work, your controller name must be exactly `myControllerNameController`. I set it up in a test project, and it is working perfectly the way I specified it here.

Comment: Already my controller name as you said.  
Name must be like that ?

`name: "4-5Segments"`

Comment: The name only applies if you are trying to match the route by name (for example, via `RouteLink` instead of `ActionLink`. Set up a new project with the default template and copy the controller, routes and `ActionLink` from my answer. Ensure that it works, then try to reconcile the differences between your current project and the new project until you find the issue. Most likely, you have another route in your solution that is matching 5 segments which is overriding this route. The first match registered always wins.

Comment: may u send your test project please :( saitenesbiyikci@gmail.com Thanks

Comment: I noticed my wrong new. I have area which called name 'admin'. This url success now but when i clicked actionLink, have requestQueryString as default. I mean that I have to edit url for this :(

Comment: What can i do for default **controller/action/2/5/1** ? Now when i click action link url like this: **control/action/2?id2=5&id3=1**

Comment: This is my root config: `routes.MapRoute(
                name: "4-5Segments",
                url: "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id2}/{id3}",
                defaults: new {  controller = "Home", action = "Index", id3 = UrlParameter.Optional }
            ).DataTokens.Add("area", "Admin");`

Comment: Please post a new question with all of the relevant details (that is, your entire route configuration and what order you put everything in). It is critical that everything be in the correct order for it to work because the first route that matches a given scenario will be the one used, and the rest ignored.

Comment: Hi, i posted new question now :) Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868923/url-without-parameter-in-mvc